# Identify the occurence number of an item in a variable

Tags: r

### Background

Now, I have a data frame shaped like:

```
example = structure(list(sid = c(39, 40, 41, 42, 42, 43, 43, 44, 45, 45, 
46, 46, 47, 48, 49, 49, 50, 51, 52, 52, 53), monthday = c("42", 
"44", "46", "410", "428", "423", "49", "411", "416", "430", "418", 
"426", "419", "420", "420", "53", "421", "424", "425", "53", 
"511")), .Names = c("sid", "monthday"), row.names = c(301L, 300L, 
298L, 296L, 282L, 288L, 297L, 295L, 294L, 281L, 293L, 285L, 292L, 
291L, 290L, 278L, 289L, 287L, 286L, 279L, 270L), class = "data.frame")
```

In other words, it is tall:

```
sid   monthday  
39     42        
40     44         
41     46        
42    410        
42    428
43    423        
43     49
```

Ultimately, I would like to make it into a wide format:

```
sid   monthday1  monthday2
39     42         NA
40     44         NA
41     46         NA
42    410        428
43    423        49
```

etc

I've been trying things with reshape and reshape2 packages and also with aggregate like:

```
library(reshape2)
temp = melt(example,id.vars=c("sid"))
data.wide <- dcast(temp, sid ~ variable, value.var="value")
```

But can't wrapp my brain around it.  It occurs to me that if I could identify the occurance of each sid, I could solve my problem.

### Immediate Problem

So how can take the tall data sid column above I make a new variable that indicates the occruence of each sid:

```
sid   occur 
39     1   
40     1   
41     1   
42     1
42     2 
43     1
43     2
```

the `occur` variable is indicating that sid values 39, 40, and 41 only appear once while 42 and 43  have first and second instances.  If I only ever had two instances, I could use duplicated() and convert that to numeric, but what is a solution that can generalize to an arbitrary number of instances?

Comment: This question is fairly confusing. The wide format you show first doesn't have much to do with the aggregated version you show later. And the wide format makes little sense: how do you get more than one monthday column? I can't see the system to it at all.

Comment: ok. i edited it and i tried to make it clearer. Hope it helps!

Comment: @Mark101001, why is `monthday` a character variable?

Comment: Dumb reasons. I did it to try to reshape without it getting transformed.  But it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ave` to generate your "times":

```
example$time <- ave(example$sid, example$sid, FUN = seq_along)
head(example)
#     sid monthday time
# 301  39       42    1
# 300  40       44    1
# 298  41       46    1
# 296  42      410    1
# 282  42      428    2
# 288  43      423    1
reshape(example, direction = "wide", idvar="sid", timevar="time")
#    sid monthday.1 monthday.2
# 301  39         42       <NA>
# 300  40         44       <NA>
# 298  41         46       <NA>
# 296  42        410        428
# 288  43        423         49
# 295  44        411       <NA>
# 294  45        416        430
# 293  46        418        426
# 292  47        419       <NA>
# 291  48        420       <NA>
# 290  49        420         53
# 289  50        421       <NA>
# 287  51        424       <NA>
# 286  52        425         53
# 270  53        511       <NA>
```

Or, with `dcast` from "reshape2" after adding your time variable:

```
dcast(example, sid ~ time, value.var="monthday")
```

Comment: Thanks!  So is it true that I needed an explicit time variable to reshape?

Comment: @Mark101001, Yes and no. If you are using base R `reshape()`, then definitely yes. If you are using `dcast()` from "reshape2", it is possible to refer to an independent vector of times instead of adding it to your "examples" `data.frame`. Something like the following should work: `myTimes <- ave(example$sid, example$sid, FUN = seq_along); dcast(example, sid ~ myTimes, value.var="monthday")`